# UriTemplate WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Is there a simple way to have multiple UriTemplates in the same definition.

```
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
```

For example I want /API/{id} and /API/{id}/ to call the same thing.  I don't want it to matter if there is / at the end or not.

Comment: Do you mean `/API/{id} and /API{id}/` or `/API/{id} and /API/{id}/ ` ?

Comment: ops yea...will correct..thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do this is to overload the function [as explained here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/23/how-to-handle-the-trailing-slash-in-a-wcf-http-service.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Not really simple, but you can use an operation selector in your behavior to strip the trailing '/', like in the example below.

```
public class StackOverflow_6073581_751090
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/API/{id}")]
        string Get(string id);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string Get(string id)
        {
            return id;
        }
    }
    public class MyBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
    {
        protected override WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector GetOperationSelector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return new MySelector(endpoint);
        }

        class MySelector : WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector
        {
            public MySelector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) : base(endpoint) { }

            protected override string SelectOperation(ref Message message, out bool uriMatched)
            {
                string result = base.SelectOperation(ref message, out uriMatched);
                if (!uriMatched)
                {
                    string address = message.Headers.To.AbsoluteUri;
                    if (address.EndsWith("/"))
                    {
                        message.Headers.To = new Uri(address.Substring(0, address.Length - 1));
                    }

                    result = base.SelectOperation(ref message, out uriMatched);
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/API/2"));
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/API/2/"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to do something like this:
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}, {id}/")] or [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id} || {id}/")]

Comment: No, each operation description is associated with a single UriTemplate. You can have more than one operation (each with its own template), and in one of them you simply call the other.

Comment: yea - I was just hoping to avoid that somehow...hmm

Comment: is there some way to set the IgnoreTrailingSlash Property in the UriTemplate Class

Comment: I don't think so, since the selector doesn't expose a way to change the UriTemplate it creates.

Answer (score 1):

This is only partially helpful, but the new [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com) library has a property on the HttpBehavior called TrailingSlashMode that can be set to Ignore or Redirect.