# IIS dumps Authorization header on redirect after WCF service call without trailing slash

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-7, hmac

I'm putting together a WCF REST service running in an IIS 7 website instance, and I'm using an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac) authentication scheme which inserts a token and the HMAC into the Authentication header. An example header list on a typical request might look like this:

```
GET http://api.mydomain.com/Contacts HTTP/1.1
Authorization: 774F035C-FRTB-4207-DDDD-31BF1534AD96:9h0Whke9Bgi3XSHPo/YSXw==
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: api.mydomain.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I have the service set up using routing instead of a .svc file, so my Global.asax looks like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Users", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(UsersService)));
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Widgets", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(WidgetsService)));
    }
```

The problem is that when the service is declared with routing like that, if IIS receives a call to a `WebGet` uri *without a trailing slash*, it does a 307 redirect to the uri *with* a trailing slash. Helpful, you'd think, **but the problem is that the redirect dumps the Authorization header.**

My service classes are all kosher and work great in every other respect. **Is there a way for me to be able to have that Authorization header be maintained in the event of a redirect?** I suspect the solution is going to be an IIS configuration thing, though I guess I could put all kinds of routing hacks in place to pick up the no-slash version of the uri.

**Update:**
I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulking/archive/2011/03/31/how-to-lose-your-authorization-head-er-with-a-bad-url.aspx) that verifies this behavior, but doesn't really give any fix.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not entirely sure why IIS is getting in the middle of things here. When you say "dumps the Authorization header" what do you mean? You mean it's re-sending it as part of the redirect or it's not sending it?

WCF wise you can probably keep the redirect from happening. This is one of those things where you'll want to slap someone at Microsoft for *almost* getting it right. The `UriTemplate` class itself has the ability to ignore trailing slashes via the aptly named [`IgnoreTrailingSlash` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate.ignoretrailingslash.aspx). Unfortunately, the WCF `WebInvoke/Get` attributes don't actually map this property through in any way and therefore always create templates that are bound exactly to whatever you type into the `UriTemplate` property.

So the simplest workaround, which is nasty I admit, is to overload the method on the WCF contract with a second signature that has the trailing slash. For example:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/Users")]
public List<User> GetUsers()
{
   .... some code here ...
}

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/Users/")]
public List<User> GetUsersSlash()
{
   return this.GetUsers();
}
```

Fugly, right? Especially bad if this is a pattern you want to repeat over and over. So another semi-but-less-hacky option is to write custom operation selector logic which you apply to your service via a custom behavior. There's more details on doing this in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073581/uritemplate-wcf/6074192#6074192).

Comment: Thanks for the response. To answer your first question, IIS is not re-sending it as part of the redirect. Looking at the article I added to my original post it looks like that's by design -- the idea according to MS is that authorization should happen again.

Comment: Yeah, ok, I totally understand that, but I'm not clear if that's EXACTLY what's happening to you. So let's step back for a second, are you the client or are other applications out of your control the clients of this service? Why wouldn't you just request the proper URL in the first place? Your service is defined as not having the trailing slash, so... that's what your clients should be requesting. The argument could be made that trailing slashes should be allowed, but technically it's a waste of bandwidth to constantly be redirecting requests because in the end, it's NOT the same URL.

Comment: Other apps out of my control will be the clients. I don't really have a problem requiring the trailing slash since it's more RESTful anyway, but I don't want the error message to be a 401 Unauthorized. I'd rather 404 them or something like that. Unfortunately, seems the service route definition makes that impossible, regardless of the `UriTemplate` I specify.

Comment: Turned out this solution doesn't seem to work. Changing the UriTemplate to include or exclude the slash seemed not to change how that redirect was constructed. Looks like the removal of the Authorization header is by design. Bummer.

Comment: Yes, I don't think you can solve this problem with a change on the server side. All I was suggesting is that you support the proper URL on the server side and make sure all your clients access that URL so that there is no redirect.